# Validate Scanner input on a numeric range

Tags: java

I'm currently creating my first game which is executed in a console.

I've been asked to validate an input which can be done with a simple code. The goal is to input, and then validate if that number is an integer, and is on a range of 1-4. If possible, the problem should be solved with basic algorithm.

The problem is that it won't give me the result I wanted. It works when I enter a string, but it loops on every number I put including the number in the range.  Does anyone know why?

```
public class Menu {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in)) {
            int input = 0;
            int min = 1;
            int max = 4;

            boolean inputValidate;

            System.out.println("Main Menu");
            System.out.println("=========");
            System.out.println("1. Play Game");
            System.out.println("2. About");
            System.out.println("3. View Saved Games");
            System.out.println("4. Exit");
            System.out.println("");

            do {
                System.out.print(">> ");
                if (!scanner.hasNextInt()) {
                    inputValidate = false;
                    System.out.println("Not a number. Please input number 1-4.");
                    scanner.nextLine();
                } else if (input <= max && !(input < min)) // if input <= 4 and input is not less than 1
                {
                    input = scanner.nextInt();
                    inputValidate = true;
                } else {
                    inputValidate = false;
                    System.out.println("Not in range. Please input number 1-4.");
                    scanner.nextLine();
                }
            } while (!(inputValidate));

            switch (input) {
                case 1:
                    break;

                case 2:
                    System.out.println("Good work!");
                    break;

                case 3:
                    break;

                case 4:
                    break;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you instantiate `input` to be `0`, but never give the user an opportunity to change this, the conditions for the first two conditionals are always false (nothing is read from the Scanner and 0 is not between `min` and `max`). Therefore, the program falls through to the `else` every time. Just add a statement before the `do-while` that will obtain a value for `input` from the user.

```
input = scanner.nextInt();

// your do-while loop
```

(You'll also probably have to adjust the code slightly to get the type of interaction you're looking for. Hint - you're reading two values from the user.)

Answer (score 2):

As Clint said the problem was in your input. Here's a demo how you can fix this,

```
try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in)) {

            int input = 0;
            int min = 1;
            int max = 4;

            boolean inputValidate = false;

            System.out.println("Main Menu");
            System.out.println("=========");
            System.out.println("1. Play Game");
            System.out.println("2. About");
            System.out.println("3. View Saved Games");
            System.out.println("4. Exit");
            System.out.println("");

            do {
                System.out.print(">> ");

                try {
                    input = scanner.nextInt();
                    if (input >= min && input <= max) {
                        inputValidate = true;
                    } else {
                        System.out
                                .println("Not in range. Please input number 1-4.");
                        scanner.nextLine();
                    }
                } catch (InputMismatchException exception) {
                    System.out
                            .println("Not a number. Please input number 1-4.");
                    scanner.nextLine();
                }

            } while (!(inputValidate));
```

Comment: Ah. InputMismatchException. I saw that once as an error. So I can actually make use of it with try-catch for any Exception errors?

Comment: Yes can you. It's a good practice and will do your job more accurately.